# Remove android:title, for action bar button?

Tags: java, android, xml

So here's my code for my `main.xml`, which is in the menu folder.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_new"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
      android:title="@null"
      android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And when I launch my app and hold down on the button, I get a toast, off the button. When I do `android:title="@null"`, I still get a toast but it's empty. How can I complete get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
getActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Comment: explanation would be nice.

Comment: OP is asking about the menu items and not the `ActionBar` itself.